# Pivot Single Column with customer details MS SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

I have relatively simplistic data source that houses customer details. A basic `SELECT *` would give :

```
CustRef CustomerName    Status  Balance
123456  John Smith      open     £1.00 
123456  Jane Smith      Open     £1.00 
321654  James Franco    Closed   £234.00 
789654  Gandalf         Open     £587,778.00
```

What I need to do is create a result set like

```
CustRef Cust1           Cust2       Status  Balance
123456  John Smith    Jane Smith    Open     £1.00 
321654  James Franco                Closed   £234.00 
789654  Gandalf                     Open     £587,778.00
```

I've attempted a few pivots but really struggle to get my head round them. How am I best achieving the results I need?

Answer (score 0):

You have two pieces of information merged into one column – which is making life difficult for you here – if you can modify the table, have CustomerSurename and CustomerFirstname! Then you can have:

```
SELECT
  c1.CustRef,
  c1.CustomerSurename as SureName,
  c1.CustomerFirstname as Cust1,
  c2.CustomerFirstname as Cust2,
  c1.Status
  c1.Balance
FROM table c1 RIGHT JOIN table c2 ON c1.CustomerSurename = c2.CustomerSurename
```

**EDIT:**

As CustRef is the comparison key (see comments), we can simply have:

```
SELECT
  c1.CustRef,
  c1.CustomerName as Cust1,
  c2.CustomerName as Cust2,
  c1.Status
  c1.Balance
FROM table c1 RIGHT JOIN table c2 ON c1.CustRef = c2.CustRef
```

**EDIT:**

Completely new approach:

```
SELECT
  CustRef,
  min(CustomerName) as Cust1,
  NULL as Cust2,
  min(Status) as Status
  min(Balance) as Balance
FROM table GROUP BY CustRef HAVING count(CustomerName) = 1

UNION

SELECT
  CustRef,
  min(CustomerName) as Cust1,
  max(CustomerName) as Cust2,
  min(Status) as Status
  min(Balance) as Balance
FROM table GROUP BY CustRef HAVING count(CustomerName) > 1
```

As far as I see or guess from the comments, status and balance are dependent from CustRef.
Apparently, however, more than one person can be assigened to a customer, thus duplicate cust refs. Well, with min and max, we can get at least two of those. So far, in the result onlwe only can have to...

An aggregate function is required for status and balance, but as these need to be all the same for one cust ref, min (or max) on these will always yield the single contained value - provided that there was no inconsistency introduced at any time.

However, we would get twice the same name if only one person exists for a cust ref entry. Thus two selects with different conditions combined in a union.

Comment: sadly the customers could have different surnames, also have no access to modify the table.

Comment: So which are the criteria to combine two corresponding customers? I assumed the surename from your example...

Comment: The CustRef is the same for each account, so if say an un married couple got a join loan you would have custNo 33456 and then 2 records. one for each person.

Comment: Well, then it is easy: WHERE c1.CustRef = c2.CustRef

Comment: You want an outer join not an inner join, otherwise "Gandalf" and "James Franco" will not be included in the result

Comment: VERY true - I overlooked this... Will adjust.

Comment: @Gandalf: Btw, will John and Jane Smith always have the same status and balance??? Then you have redundant data. Possibly a good idea for a little redesign (see [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)).

Comment: the data was fabricated - after doing the above this doesn't work. Simply get a syntax error. Far as I'm aware you cant do a INNER or OUTER join without creating relational fields....

SELECT c1.CustRef
    , c1.CustomerName
    , c2.CustomerName
 FROM #tblTMP002 AS c1 RIGHT JOIN  #tblTMP002 AS c2 ON c1.CustRef = c2.CustRef
WHERE c1.CustRef = c2.CustRef

however this gives duplicated rows.

Comment: Not my day today - of course, need to replace where with on... Do I see this right, cust ref shall only appear once - is the order of cust1 and cust2 of relevance?

Comment: order doesnt matter, just turning what is two rows into one is really the goal.